# How can I pick the latest record from the left join in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table view defined as:

```
CREATE view [SIR_SUMMARY]
AS
    SELECT
        dimsite.[SiteCode],
        dimsite.[SiteName],
        dimsite.[CityOrLocal] as City,
        dimsite.[State],
        dimsite.PostCode as Zip,
        analysis.[ProductName] as GardeName,
        analysis.[AnalysisTypeName] as ReportingType,
        analysis.LastObsDate as ReportingDate
    FROM
        LOBDW.bjs.udv_BJS_DIM_SITE dimsite
    LEFT JOIN 
       [LOBDW].[bjs].[udv_BJS_FACT_SIRA_ANALYSES] analysis ON dimsite.LegSiteId = analysis.LegSiteId
```

The above view returns three records for different **ReportingDate**; I would like to return single row for the latest **ReportingDate**.

How can I do that?

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done. Im using mssql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
create view [SIR_SUMMARY] as
    select . . .
    from LOBDW.bjs.udv_BJS_DIM_SITE bds left join
         (select a.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by LegSiteId order by ReportingDate desc) as seqnum
          from [LOBDW].[bjs].[udv_BJS_FACT_SIRA_ANALYSES] a
         ) a
         on bds.LegSiteId = a.LegSiteId and a.seqnum = 1;
```

Note that I changed the table aliases.  I think shorter ones are easier to use in the query.

Comment: One more quick question..Can I add partition by condition for more than one column? eg LegSiteId and ProductName ?

Comment: @Ratha . . . Yes, just list the columns . . . `partition by LegSiteId, ProductName`.